# ImportError: cannot import name route in python bottle

Tags: python

I am trying to start learning python bottle framework, I've installed python 2.7.11, and installed pip too, I've installed bottle using

```
pip install bottle
Collecting bottle
  Using cached bottle-0.12.9.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: bottle
  Running setup.py install for bottle ... done
Successfully installed bottle-0.12.9
```

Now I tried to run the example code from bottle website

```
from bottle import route, run, template
@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

when I run this code it throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SID/Desktop/bottle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bottle import route, run, template
  File "C:/Users/SID/Desktop\bottle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bottle import route, run, template
ImportError: cannot import name route
```

I don't know what went wrong could some one guide me, Is it the error with the code? or in bottle installation?

Note: I Tried python 3.4.3 too still facing same error while running program and I'm using windows 8.1 in virtual box

Comment: check whether  bottle is being installed in python 3.4.3 or python 2.7.11?

Comment: Ya, its installed in both and I am sure of where i'm using this bottle as i said below do i need this bottle.py file in the same location where my code is? Because the code only works when i have bottle.py in the same location with my code, Is there any other way i could solve this issue without keeping bottle.py in the same folder where my project is?

Comment: Is your file name is 'bottle.py' ?

Comment: This was my issue.  Once I renamed it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `bottle.py` file within your project folder. Problem occurred because python module `C:/Users/SID/Desktop/bottle.py` shadowed `bottle.py` module which installed by pip. Rename file which shadow real `bottle.py` module to fix import problem.

Location of file which shall be renamed is `C:/Users/SID/Desktop/bottle.py`.

Comment: you mean bottle.py within "C:\Python27\Scripts" folder, I've renamed it as "bottle-renamed.py", but it still didn't helped me

Comment: @Sundararajan rename that file back to previous name and adjust name of `C:/Users/SID/Desktop/bottle.py`

Comment: Actually, Its working now after I changed the location of my python script to the same location where the "bottle.py" present. Thank you so much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

When a module named bottle is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, as in this case it then searches for a file named bottle.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:

- the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
- PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
- the installation-dependent default.

Make sure bottle is in PYTHONPATH. More info on PYTHONPATH [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: Actually, Its working now after I changed the location of my python script to the same location where the "bottle.py" present. Thank you so much for helping me, but shall you explain me why both bottle.py and mycode.py should be in the same location. I am now reading about the PYTHONPATH link you gave, thanks for sharing info...